# Error with creating EXE from Python GUI

Tags: pyqt, py2exe, python-3.5

I am using python 3.5 along with pyQT to create a GUI.

I am using py2exe that I have read works with python 3. After searching google, I believe my issue is something to do with the packages I am using.

My python file has the following imports:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from collections import Counter  
import collections
import math

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import os
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import random
import re
```

I am using the syntax for py2exe:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

Where my setup file has the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
print('Running')
setup(windows=['myProgram.py'], options={"py2exe": {"includes": ["sip","PyQt4" "PyQt4.QtGui","PyQt4.Qt"]}}) 
print("Done!")
```

Buy when I run py2exe, my command window just freezes and there are no error messages. I have spent weeks trying to find a solution but have not been succesfull.

I have also read that another exe program (pyinstaller) doesn't work with imports only from.  Not sure if this is relevant to my problem.

any help would be gratefully appreciated, there is not much help on google.

Thanks
Jason

Comment: just a random suggestion, have you tried `cx_freeze` i was having issues with `py2exe`, using `cx_freeze` fixed my problem

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately cx_freeze doesn't work with python 3.5.1